# The Median Game - For Money

Tags: optimization, game-theory

Inspired by [this interesting puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115595/the-median-game) which was quickly solved.

Five friends play a simple game with the following rules:

1. Players play consecutively one after the other.
2. Each player must call out a whole number between 1 and 10 (inclusive), such that it hasn't been called out already.
3. The winner is the player whose number is the median of all called out numbers.
4. The winner receives \$100. At any point, players are allowed to "bribe" others to guess in a particular way (e.g. Player 5 says to Player 4 "I'll give you \$20 if you choose a 3.")

What should be the optimal strategy for each player to maximize their expected profit?  What is the expected profit for each player?

Assume that the players' only interest is maximizing their own profit, and they will choose randomly if their available options all have the same expected profit.

Comment: Interesting. Can they bribe others to not to bribe others?  :-P

Comment: I think for this to work you need some kind of irrevocability: if a players has said something, they cannot renege on whatever they have said. This means you can't allow them to bribe (or talk) "at any point". Instead it's most natural if everyone can only make their offer before they choose their number. I asked a similar puzzle in this fashion https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109112/outmaneuver-your-opponents-in-the-duel

Comment: I think the "bribes" need a lot of further clarification for the question to be answerable.

Comment: Can people update their offers repeatedly in a bribing escalade?  Must all amouts be in whole dollars, or dollars  and cents?

Comment: I believe that the optimum strategy may depend on weather the bribes are public or private. So is everyone aware of the 'deals' each player is trying to make, or can groups of two or more players have conversations private from the others?

Comment: Let's say all offers are made publicly.

Comment: Does a player must pay the bribe he offered only if they are the winner, or must they pay in any case ?

Comment: Can a player utter other convincing/binding statements, e.g. a  threat like: "If you do not bribe me, I will call out 4"?

Comment: Who can bribe when is also important.  It must be fixed.  If player A wants to bribe player B, and player C want to do the same for the same number, then A might want to wait until C offered his bribe.  And vice-versa.  So there must be a clear rule of who can announce deals (aka bribes) and when.  For example before any player announces his number, every player in turn can offer a bribe, just once.

Comment: By the way, how does a bribe work?  As an open contract?  I.e. the briber makes an offer and the money is transferred only if the wanted number is indeed called?  Or as an immediate engagement?  I.e. after receiving an offer, the player must accept or refuse immediately.  If he accepts, the money is transferred and the bribee must call the requested number, making the subsequent bribes pointless.

Comment: I don't think OP has a solution for this. This is way too complex.

Answer (score 1):

I claim that

> introducing bribes doesn't change how the game is played!

This is because

> there will always be two or more players who would benefit from a bribe, yet the player being bribed could accept any and all of them. The bribers, recognizing this, choose not to bribe at all, because if one offered $\\\$x$, then another would offer $\\\$x+\epsilon$, and so on, until all bribers offered $\\\$100$. At this point, the player being bribed has no more incentive to behave a certain way than if no money was offered.

To see this, let's understand how a game with players A, B, C, D, and E plays out:

> For A to have any chance of winning, they must choose a number with two more numbers on either side. This allows 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, or 8, but it will become apparent that they prefer one of the numbers in the middle, 5 or 6. Assume WLOG they choose 5.

> B picks the other number to set their chance of winning equal to A's; in our example, they pick 6.

> To have any chance of winning, C must pick adjacent to A or B. Suppose they pick 4.

> Now comes the interesting part: D and E are guaranteed to lose, so their only source of income is bribes. Everyone's actions will now play out based on the following information:
>
>  A wins if and only if D and E pick from opposite sides of A.
>  B wins if and only if D and E pick from B's side of A.
>  C wins if and only if D and E pick from C's side of A.

> Therefore, A does not bribe D at all, because that would risk D being counter-bribed; instead, they can always wait to bribe E to pick opposite to D. However, B and C each need D on their side to win, but this runs into the runaway bribing situation, so *neither bribe D at all*. Thus, D picks randomly and their expected profit is $\\\$0$.

> Suppose WLOG D chooses from B's side. This means A and B each need E on their side to win. So again, neither of them bribe E; E picks randomly, and their expected profit is $\\\$0$.

> Thus, by the symmetry of their choices, A and B each have the same chance of winning. C's chance of winning is $\frac37\cdot\frac26=\frac17$, so A's and B's chances each become $\frac37$.

This gives the following approximate expected profits:

> A: $\\\$42.86$.
>  B: $\\\$42.86$.
>  C: $\\\$14.29$.
>  D: $\\\$00.00$.
>  E: $\\\$00.00$.

Comment: Can you explain further why bribing is suboptimal? And does the logic apply between players who have different winning chances?

Comment: Under this answer, C, D, and E have poor expected profits. What's to stop them realising this and devising a scheme where E gives C and D 100/3 dollars each in exchange for setting things up so that E wins the pot (which can be done regardless of how A and B choose)? Is it an assumption that the players don't trust each other enough not to renege?

Answer (score 0):

With several assumption what is possible, I come to the following:

> player 1 and 2 have no better play than calling out 5 and 6.

> 1 and 2 are natural allies and so are 4 and 5.
>  Neither team wants a bidding war, so player 4 will offer X$ for 3 to bid non-adjacent (and thus get control).
> Here x should be such that player 3 decides randomly; then team 1-2 will not bid.

> case 1: If player 3 bids adjacent (i.e. does not take a bribe):
> - player 3 will win 1/7 of the time (if 4 and 5 choose its side; 3/7*2/6 chance)
> - player 1 or 2 will win otherwise with equal chance 3/7

> So player 4 will offer a 100$/7 bribe for 1,2,3,8,9 and 10.
>  Player 3 takes a random number and thus the bribe 6/8th of the time.

> case 2: If player 3 takes the bribe:
>  If player 4 does not take a bribe he will call 4 if player 3 called high and 7 if player 3 called low, for a 50% win chance when player 5 claaes randomly.
>  - Thus player 5 will offer player 4 50$ to let him win (i.e for 2 numbers, instead of the one he would normally choose.
>  Then player 4 decides randomly, and again the rest will not start a bidding war.

> case 2a: If player 4 also takes the bribe (2/3rd * 6/8th of the time)
> - player 3 gets 100/7(received)
> - player 4 gets 50(received)-100/7(paid)
> - player 5 gets 100(won)-50(paid)
> case 2b: If player 4 does not take the bribe (1/3rd * 6/8th of the time)
> - player 4 gets 50(win) - 100/7(paid)
> - player 3 gets 100/7(received)
> - player 1,2 get 25(win)

Total expected gain:

> `player 1,2:  1/4*3/7 + 0        + 1/4*1/4  =  17.86$`
>  `player 3:    1/4*1/7 + 1/2*1/7  + 1/4*1/7  =  14.28$`
> `player 4:    0       + 1/2*5/14 + 1/4*4/14 =  25.00%`
> `player 5:    0       + 1/2*1/2  + 0        =  25.00$`
>  Addition; the entire calculation probably fails, since player 3 can offer  player 2 a bribe (of at least 3.58$) to call out 7 i.s.o. 6 and then call out 6

> Note that there is room for 'meta gaming'; If player 4 bribes player 3 for a lesser amount (or not at all), both player 5 and player 4 will want the other to increase the bid to 100$/7, and both have an incentive to do it themself.